# toll-free bridged objects, retain and release

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation, nsmutableset

I'm currently looking at a `NSMutableSet` created by the function `CFSetCreateMutable()`. The documentation states that the return value of `CFSetCreateMutable()` is toll-free bridged, meaning that I can simply cast it into a `NSMutableSet`. Does this mean that sending it the `release` message is perfectly valid? Am I always safe to assume that I can always treat such objects as if they were `alloc`'ed via an NS-class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just imagine that `CFSetCreateMutable()` is equivalent to [[NSMutableSet alloc] init] in that you have to release the object after you are done with it. If you are using ARC, you can cast a CFMutableSet to an NSMutableSet using a bridged cast: `(__bridge_transfer NSMutableSet *)theCFSet`. This will tell ARC that it is responsible for releasing the set after it goes out of scope.

Comment: So basically, toll-free bridge means "equivalent in all intents and purposes"? Nice! Sadly, I cannot use ARC, because I need to deploy to iOS 4. Oh well, if get to do grunt work on memory management, I will at least get a deeper understanding of it all (that's not to say I really miss RAII from C++!)

Answer (score 1):

> The documentation states that the return value of CFSetCreateMutable() is toll-free bridged, meaning that I can simply cast it into a NSMutableSet. Does this mean that sending it the release message is perfectly valid?

Yes. [This is explicitly guaranteed in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html):

> Note from the example that the memory management functions and methods are also interchangeable—you can use `CFRelease` with a Cocoa object and `release` and `autorelease` with a Core Foundation object.

---

> Am I always safe to assume that I can always treat such objects as if they were alloc'ed via an NS-class?

Not really: *Currently*, anything that exists in common between CFType and NSObject, such as `-description`/`CFCopyDescription`, works regardless of how you created the object, but they're not all explicitly guaranteed to work like the memory-management messages are.